# Does "Select New" in linq trigger an evaluation / load?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, yield, fluent-interface

I'm currently trying to create a class which implements `IEnumerable<T>` in order to construct a Hierarchy from a flat list of objects which have references to each other through a ParentId property. I'd like to write a fluent interface for this so I can do something like this

```
IEnumerable<Tab> tabs = GetTabs();

IEnumerable<TabNode> tabNodes = tabs.AsHierarchy().WithStartLevel(2).WithMaxDepth(5);
```

So, about the yield statement, I wonder whether I could do something like this within my `NodeHierarchy : IEnumerable<TabNode>` class:

```
private IEnumerable<TabNode> _nodes;

public NodeHierarchy(IEnumerable<Tab> tabs)
{
    _nodes = CreateHierarchy(tabs);
}

public IEnumerable<TabNode> CreateHierarchy(IEnumerable<Tab> tabs)
{
    /* About this block: I'm trying to find the top level 
    nodes of the first tab collection, maybe this is done poorly? */
    var tabIds = tabs.Select(t => t.TabID);
    IEnumerable<TabNode> nodes = from tab in tabs
                             where !tabIds.Contains(tab.ParentId)
                                 select new TabNode {
                                            Tab = node,
                                            ChildNodes = CreateHierarchy(tabs, node.TabID, 1),
                                            Depth = 1 };
    return nodes;
}
```

or whether I would have to do something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<TabNode> _nodes;

public NodeHierarchy(IEnumerable<Tab> tabs)
{
    _nodes = CreateHierarchy(tabs);
}

public IEnumerable<TabNode> CreateHierarchy(IEnumerable<Tab> tabs)
{
var tabIds = tabs.Select(t => t.TabID);
IEnumerable<Tab> startingNodes = from tab in tabs
                                 where !tabIds.Contains(tab.ParentId)
                                 select tab;

foreach(Tab node in startingNodes)
{
    yield return
    new TabNode()
        {
        Tab = node,
        ChildNodes = CreateHierarchy(tabs, node.TabID, 1),
        Depth = 1
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you reformat your code using spaces instead of tabs? It's pretty unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks, I'm working on it... the copy paste job didn't really work here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `select new` will not trigger evaluation. This will map to a call to:

```
 .Select(tab => new TabNode {...})
```

And note that `Select` (for LINQ-to-Objects, at least) is essentially something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TDest> Select<TSource,TDest>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource,TDest> selector)
{
    foreach(TSource item in source)
    {
        yield return selector(source);
    }
}
```

The key point here being that it evaluates lazy - not all at once.

Either approach should be comparable - the only difference is that without `yield return`, *some* code will run immediately - but only the code to build the `.Where(...).Select(...)` chain - it won't actually process the rows until you start iterating the result.

Furthermore, depending on the data source, that approach can actually be more efficient - for example, with a LINQ-to-SQL backend, as the TSQL generator can skip the unnecessary columns.